# Replace character on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this piece of HTML

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <fieldset> 
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="3-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">3_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="12-rosas" checked='checked' id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">12_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="18-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">18_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="24-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">24_rosas
                <br />
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to replace the "_" character on the option text with a white space using  javascript or jQuery.

I have tried with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your jquery code you tried?

Comment: option text? where is that?

Comment: I don't think it is good to have multiple id with same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to get each text after radio button and then replace `_` with space. You need to wrap the text in some html element like `label`, `span` etc and then use `.replace('_',' ');)`.

See below code -

HTML - I have wrapped text into label

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
         <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
         <fieldset> 
            <br />
            <input type="radio" value="3-rosas" id="cantidad" 
                    name="attribute_cantidad">
            <label>3_rosas</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" value="12-rosas" checked='checked' 
                   id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">
            <label>12_rosas</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" value="18-rosas" id="cantidad"
                   name="attribute_cantidad">
            <label>18_rosas</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" value="24-rosas" id="cantidad" 
            name="attribute_cantidad">
            <label>24_rosas</label>
            <br />
         </fieldset>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $('table td.value fieldset label').each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace('_',' '));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/51fdzrhs/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, I was banging my head on the wall with this. I wasn't wrapping the element with a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

```
$('.value').find('input:radio').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, ' ');
    $(this).next('span').html(val);
});
```

Please check below fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1wpj6sa/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.contents()` method, then replace any `_` in each text node as follows:

```
$('.value > fieldset').contents().each(function() {
    this.nodeType !== 3 || ( this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/_/g,' ') );
});
```

```js
$('.value > fieldset').contents().each(function() {
    this.nodeType !== 3 || ( this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/_/g,' ') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <fieldset> 
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="3-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">3_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="12-rosas" checked='checked' id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">12_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="18-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">18_rosas
                <br />
                <input type="radio" value="24-rosas" id="cantidad" name="attribute_cantidad">24_rosas
                <br />
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```